# How to Show Widget while p:fileUpload is in progress

Tags: java, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using this fileUpload to upload documents from an Excel sheet.

```
                    <h:form id="leForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p:fileUpload
                             mode="advanced"  showButtons="FALSE"
                             label="{messages['upload.xls']}"                                                       
                            fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}"                                                           
                            id="uploadCargaMasiva" update="messages3, :tabs:formTab2:documentoList" auto="true"                                                                                     
                            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/"/>
                        <p:growl id="messages3" escape="true" sticky="false"
                            lifetime="800" showDetail="false" />                            
                    </h:form>
```

This works as expected.  My issue is that I need to show a p:Dialog while the upload is in progress, and I can't find the way of doing this.

This is my dialog:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
    <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
</p:dialog>
```

I don't know how to call it or where :(.  Any suggestions?

Comment: PrimeFaces fileUpload has `onstart`, `onerror` and `oncomplete` for clientSide behavior. Did you tried this? Like `onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"`

Comment: Thanks for the response!, Tried it, but it didn't work. Or maybe am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What primefaces-version are you using?

Comment: Primefaces 3.4 does not provide `onerror` afaik but the other two should work. But the syntax should be `onstart="statusDialog.show()"` - my previous answer was related to PF 5.0

Comment: onstart works fine!, but oncomplete seems not working : I'm using statusDialog.hide() , but it never dissapears :/

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the fileupload itself? Does the fileupload finish? Otherwise I have no idea. For PF 5.0 it works for me, unfortunately I do not have the possibility to test it with PF 3.4 at the moment

Comment: Yes, the upload works fine. I managed to do it in the bean with : 
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("widgetHide()");  
widgetHide is a JS function with  statusDialog.hide(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                <h:form id="leForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload
                         mode="advanced"  showButtons="FALSE"
                         label="{messages['upload.xls']}"                                                       
                        fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}"                                                           
                        id="uploadCargaMasiva" update="messages3, :tabs:formTab2:documentoList" auto="true"                                                                                                            onstart="statusDialog.show()"
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/"/>
                    <p:growl id="messages3" escape="true" sticky="false"
                        lifetime="800" showDetail="false" />                            
                </h:form>
```

In the bean.java I added this line at the end of handleFileUpload:

```
     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("widgetHide()");
```

widgetHide is a JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function widgetHide()
    {                                   
        statusDialog.hide();    
    }

</script>
```

As was suggested, onstart and oncomplete shoud do the trick, but for some reason oncomplete wasn't working . So I had to do this walkaround to make it work.